# R packages to fit three dimensional data using radial basis functions

Tags: r, regression

I'm interested in fitting a three dimensional surface to some spatial data (x, y, z) using a radial basis function approach.  I have found that radial basis functions apppear in the R package 'fields' but would like to find an example where it has been used to fit a surface to points in three dimensions. I would thankful if somebody could point me towards or  provide a simple example that I could use as a start.

Comment: Do you want your basis functions to be a function of radius, like spherical Bessel functions, or a function of spherical angle, like spherical harmonics? If the latter, then that is an angular basis function, where you can say some quantity varies with azimuth and elevation angles. In your case the quantity could be "elevation", or radius, of the surface.

Comment: Ricardo thanks for you comment.  My goal is to fit a closed solid shape to the points - enclosing a 3D volume of a particular rock type in a mineral deposit (the points are from drill holes).  I have tried using triangulations and also kriging on a regular 3D grid but not happy with either result.  My understanding is there are number options I could try using using the field package but would like to see an example if possible.

Comment: Thanks for converting that non-question.  I assume I don't need to delete the original?  I don't know your R package toolset, but I have worked with spherical harmonics and spherical Bessel functions in the past.  Spherical harmonics can help you make a surface surrounding a volume.  Spherical Bessel functions can help you make density variations within such a volume.  If all you want is the "hull" shape, then I think the angular basis functions called spherical harmonics is one function you might look for in your toolset.